# How to cache the Images that is loaded in TableViewCell - Firebase and Obj-C

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nscache

I use firebase to upload messages, images, videos. I'm able to upload and download the images, messages, and videos. However, when I populate data in UITableView and scroll the UITableView, the image gets changed for every scroll. How do I cached the images that are already downloaded? I got a reference from [this site](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GX4mcOOUrWQ&t=138s), where he's creating a NSCache using the extension file(from 17:22 Mins). It is in Swift, but I want the same thing in Objective-c.

Can somebody help me in getting the same thing in Objective-c?

Below is the code to download and display image in the UITableView

```
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"GroupCell";

  _groupCell = (GroupTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
  _groupModel = _groups[indexPath.row];
  _groupCell.groupName.text = _groupModel.groupName;
  _groupCell.recentMessage.text = @"Development is in progress";
  _groupCell.recentMessageTime.text = @"6:00 PM";
  _groupCell.unreadMessages.text = @"5";
  _groupCell.groupDisplayPic.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"defaultprofilepic.png"];

  NSString *groupPicUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",_groupModel.groupPic];



  //if (groupPicUrl!=nil) {
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:groupPicUrl];
    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
    NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [session dataTaskWithURL:url completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {


      //Download Images
      if (data) {
        _groupProfilePic = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
        if (_groupProfilePic) {
          dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            GroupTableViewCell *updateCell = (id)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
            if (updateCell) {
              updateCell.groupDisplayPic.image = _groupProfilePic;

              UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(_groupCell.groupDisplayPic.bounds.size, NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);
              [[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:updateCell.groupDisplayPic.bounds cornerRadius:100.0] addClip];
              [_groupProfilePic drawInRect:updateCell.groupDisplayPic.bounds];
              updateCell.groupDisplayPic.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
              UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
            }

          });
        }
      } 

    }];
    [dataTask resume];

  return _groupCell;
}
```

//Update
Tried so far:

```
_groupCell.groupDisplayPic.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"defaultprofilepic.png"];
  NSString *groupPicUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",_groupModel.groupPic];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:groupPicUrl];
    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];

  _groupProfilePic = [[GP sharedInstance]getCachedImageForKey:groupPicUrl];
  if (_groupProfilePic) {
    NSLog(@"Image loaded from cache");
    _groupCell.groupDisplayPic.image = _groupProfilePic;

  }
  else
  {
          NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [session dataTaskWithURL:url completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {

            if (data) {
              _groupProfilePic = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
              if (_groupProfilePic) {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                 GroupTableViewCell * updateCell = (id)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
                  if (updateCell) {
                     updateCell.groupDisplayPic.image = _groupProfilePic;
                   // _groupCell.groupDisplayPic.image = _groupProfilePic;

                    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(updateCell.groupDisplayPic.bounds.size, NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);
                    [[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:updateCell.groupDisplayPic.bounds cornerRadius:100.0] addClip];
                    [_groupProfilePic drawInRect:updateCell.groupDisplayPic.bounds];
                    updateCell.groupDisplayPic.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
                    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
                  }

                });
              }
            }

        }];
      [dataTask resume];
```

//Helper Method - Just followed the same steps from this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28366397/nscache-initialization-for-storing-uiimage-ios)

GP.h

```
 #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

    @interface GP : NSObject

    +(GP*)sharedInstance;

    // set
    - (void)cacheImage:(UIImage*)image forKey:(NSString*)key;
    // get
    -(UIImage*)getCachedImageForKey:(NSString*)key;

    @end

    #import "GP.h"

    static GP *sharedInstance;

    @interface GP ()

    @property (nonatomic, strong) NSCache *imageCache;

    @end
```

GP.m

```
#import "GP.h"

@implementation GP


+ (GP*)sharedInstance {
  static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
  dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
    sharedInstance = [[GP alloc] init];
  });
  return sharedInstance;
}
- (instancetype)init {
  self = [super init];
  if (self) {
    self.imageCache = [[NSCache alloc] init];
  }
  return self;
}

- (void)cacheImage:(UIImage*)image forKey:(NSString*)key {
  [self.imageCache setObject:image forKey:key];
}

- (UIImage*)getCachedImageForKey:(NSString*)key {
  return [self.imageCache objectForKey:key];
}

@end
```

Comment: save them into the app's cache folder and restore back them when you need; or if the current image is not available there yet, download it and whenever it is available locally in the cache, use it in your cell view.

Comment: How exactly to do that in Objective-C? Can you please show me some example?

Comment: show us what you have tried so far and tell us whare you have been stuck at.

Comment: @holex I have updated

Comment: @holex - any idea?